# Extract URLs from a website ( The Hindu) which uses google search console using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm trying to extract links from website using beautiful soup.The website link is `https://www.thehindu.com/search/?q=central+vista&sort=relevance&start=#gsc.tab=0&gsc.q=central%20vista&gsc.page=1`

The code which i used is given below

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url=[]

url = 'https://www.thehindu.com/search/?q=central+vista&sort=relevance&start=#gsc.tab=0&gsc.q=central%20vista&gsc.page=1'
reqs = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(reqs.text, 'html.parser')

urls = []
for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    print(link.get('href'))
    urls.append(link.get('href'))
```

The code runs and gives all the urls present in the website except the one present in the google search console which is the required part.I am basically stuck. Can someone help me to sort it out?

Answer (score 0):

The data you see is loaded with JavaScript, so `beautifulsoup` doesn't see it. You can use `requests` + `re`/`json` modules to get the data:

```py
import re
import json
import requests

url = "https://cse.google.com/cse/element/v1"

params = {
    "rsz": "filtered_cse",
    "num": "10",
    "hl": "sk",
    "source": "gcsc",
    "gss": ".com",
    "cselibv": "f275a300093f201a",
    "cx": "264d7caeb1ba04bfc",
    "q": "central vista",
    "safe": "active",
    "cse_tok": "AB1-RNWPlN01WUQgebV0g3LpWU6l:1670351743367",
    "lr": "",
    "cr": "",
    "gl": "",
    "filter": "0",
    "sort": "",
    "as_oq": "",
    "as_sitesearch": "",
    "exp": "csqr,cc,4861326",
    "callback": "google.search.cse.api3099",
}

data = requests.get(url, params=params).text
data = re.search(r"(?s)\((.*)\)", data).group(1)
data = json.loads(data)

for r in data["results"]:
    print(r["url"])
```

Prints:

```
https://www.thehindu.com/news/national/estimated-cost-of-central-vista-revamp-plan-without-pmo-goes-up-to-13450-cr/article33358124.ece
https://www.thehindu.com/news/national/central-vista-project-sc-dismisses-plea-against-delhi-hc-verdict-refusing-to-halt-work/article35031575.ece
https://www.thehindu.com/opinion/editorial/monumental-hurry-on-central-vista-project/article31734021.ece
https://www.thehindu.com/news/national/central-vista-new-buildings-on-kg-marg-africa-avenue-proposed-for-relocating-govt-offices/article31702494.ece
https://www.thehindu.com/society/beyond-the-veils-of-secrecy-the-central-vista-project-is-both-the-cause-and-effect-of-its-own-multiple-failures/article32980560.ece
https://www.thehindu.com/news/national/estimated-cost-of-central-vista-revamp-plan-without-pmo-goes-up-to-13450-cr/article33358124.ece%3Fhomepage%3Dtrue
https://www.thehindu.com/news/national/work-on-new-parliament-central-vista-avenue-projects-on-track/article36296821.ece
https://www.thehindu.com/news/national/2466-trees-removed-for-central-vista-projects-so-far-govt/article65665595.ece
https://www.thehindu.com/news/national/central-vista-avenue-redevelopment-project-to-be-completed-by-july-18-puri/article65611471.ece%3Fhomepage%3Dtrue
https://www.thehindu.com/news/national/central-vista-jharkhand-firm-is-lowest-bidder-for-vice-president-enclave/article37310541.ece
```

Comment: Thanks Andrej! Can you guide me through the parameters section? Also, if I need to parse the results across multiple pages, do I have to manually alter the parameters, or is there another method?